# jQuery Cookie Not Keeping Updated Value

Tags: jquery, cookies, magento2, session-cookies

I am trying to set a default value of "false" when someone first enters the site. Then once a button is clicked, it will update. This works just fine. The issue though is when they refresh or go back to the page, it will reset back to "false" no matter what. I already have all cookies set to expire after a year. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong?

```
require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui','Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'], function($){
   jQuery(document).ready( function() {
       $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
       var pairs = document.cookie.split(";");
       var cookies = {};
       for (var i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
           var pair = pairs[i].split("=");
           cookies[(pair[0] + '').trim()] = unescape(pair.slice(1).join('='));
       }
       let check_cookie = cookies.cookie_consent;
       if (check_cookie !== null && check_cookie !== undefined) {
           let checkCookies =  check_cookie.split(",");
           for (var i = 0; i < checkCookies.length; i++) {
               let cookieTags = checkCookies[i];
               let tagName = cookieTags.substring(0, cookieTags.indexOf('='));
               let tagValue = cookieTags.substr(cookieTags.indexOf("=") + 1);
               let tag = "#"+ tagName;
               if(tagValue === 'true'){
                   jQuery(tag).prop('checked', true);
               } else {
                   jQuery(tag).prop('checked', false);
               }
           }
       }
       $('.open-model-button').click(function () {
           $('#popup-modal').modal('openModal');
           $('.modal-footer').hide();
       });
   });
});
require(['jquery', 'mage/cookies'], function ($) {
    jQuery.cookie('rlx-consent', 'false', { expires: 365, path: '/', domain: "davidfairclough.com" });
});
```

Then I also have the code for each button clicked

```
function accept() {
    jQuery.cookie('rlx-consent', 'true', { expires: 365, path: '/', domain: "davidfairclough.com" });
}

function acceptSelected() {
    let google_analytics = document.getElementsByName('google_analytics');
    let gtm = document.getElementsByName('gtm');
    let rolex = document.getElementsByName('rolex');
    let cookieCmp = 'google_analytics=' + google_analytics[0].checked + "%" + 'gtm=' + gtm[0].checked + "%" + 'rolex=' + rolex[0].checked;
    jQuery.cookie('cookie_consent', cookieCmp, { expires: 365, path: '/', domain: "davidfairclough.com" });
    jQuery.cookie('rlx-consent', 'true', { expires: 365, path: '/', domain: "davidfairclough.com" });
}

function decline() {
    jQuery.cookie('rlx-consent', 'false', { expires: 365, path: '/', domain: "davidfairclough.com" });
}
```

Comment: If you're using `jQuery.cookie()`, why does the first code block parse `document.cookie` by itself?

Comment: Which cookie are you having trouble with? The first code block deals with `consent_cookie`, but the rest deals with `rlx-consent`.

Comment: This was done by me and someone else so there will be some code that probably doesn't need to be there.

Comment: consent_cookie is good. I should have deleted that. That's another cookie added if someone decides they only want to accept certain things instead of accepting all.

Comment: You don't have any code that checks if the cookie exists before setting it. So it always sets it to `false`.

Comment: How would I go about writing this? I am a newbie to jQuery and can only do so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test whether the cookie already exists before initializing it.

```
if (!jQuery.cookie('rlx-consent')) {
  jQuery.cookie('rlx-consent', 'false', { expires: 365, path: '/', domain: "davidfairclough.com" });
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That did it!! This has been a real pain in the ass. You are my hero.